# Bat file to create a list of files and there paths in the same directory as the bat file

Tags: list, batch-file, ffmpeg, video-processing

I want to create a bat file that creates a list of files and there paths (MyList.txt). Saves that file to the same directory the bat file is being run in.

This is what I am trying to accomplish with the MyList.txt. I would like to have the files in order as well.

```
file 'E:\Adobe\Projects\Work\191215 December\1\CONTENTS\CLIPS001\AA3023\AA302301.MXF'
file 'E:\Adobe\Projects\Work\191215 December\1\CONTENTS\CLIPS001\AA3023\AA302302.MXF'
file 'E:\Adobe\Projects\Work\191215 December\1\CONTENTS\CLIPS001\AA3023\AA302303.MXF'
file 'E:\Adobe\Projects\Work\191215 December\1\CONTENTS\CLIPS001\AA3023\AA302304.MXF'
```

After this, I would like FFMPEG to concat those files `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i MyList.txt -c copy -map 0 Output.mxf` and output that to the same directory as well, but I think it will do that currently.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
@echo off
ECHO Creating MXF Concat List
dir /a /-p /o:gen > "%~dp1MXF_list.txt"
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i MXF_list.txt -c copy -map 0 Output.mxf
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@echo off

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`dir /b /a-d *.mxf`) do echo file '%~dp0%%a'>>MXF_list.txt

ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i MXF_list.txt -c copy -map 0 Output.mxf
```

Comment: Is this a working solution to your question? I ask because it's different from that which you posted in the comments, _(and was asked to transfer to your question body, but didn't)_. If it is, are you satisfied with it? are you interested in improving it? or receiving alternative solutions?